# New clone of repo - actionpack is giving me argument errors from the gem file I don't understand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionpack

This is way over my head. Just cloned down a repo. Updated a few gems, all that seemed to go fine. But when I try to run rails s or rails c I get this error:

```
...vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.4/actionpack-5.2.4.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:111:in 'initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
```

I thought maybe it was because I hadn't run rails db:migrate yet to rebuild the DB, but I get the same error trying to do that too. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try [`bundle pristine`](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-pristine.1.html)

Comment: Tried it, gives me the same errors. I don't think its actually a problem with the gem. I think it has something to do with my database not existing (it was gitignored). so actionpack is throwing errors about not seeing a DB at all. I'm not sure how to rebuild it though